# How to do counter with smarty?

Tags: php, smarty, counter

I want to do one counter with Smarty.

In php I do `$i++` to create a counter and after I use `if()` with `if($i%3 == 0)`.

How could I do the same but with Smarty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To initialise a counter in Smarty, you just need to specify the variable, and optionally provide the `start` point and `skip` (incremental offset):

```
{counter start=0 skip=3 assign=var} // Initialise the counter **and** log the first output
{counter}<br />
{counter}<br />
{counter}<br />
```

This will start a counter at 1, and increment by 3, so this will output:

```
1<br />
4<br />
7<br />
10<br />
```

Then you can check if a particular number in the counter is divisible by three with:

```
{if $var is div by 3}
   ...
{/if}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Coud you help me with my code?

        {if empty($tsCategorias)}
            <center>No hemos creado categorías en el sistema de ayuda</center>
        {else}
     <table align="center">
            {counter start=0 skip=3 assign=i}
      <tr>
                {foreach from=$tsCategorias item=c}
                    <td style="padding-right:150px;"> <img src="{$tsConfig.images}/icons/folder.png"> {$c.c_nombre} ()</td>
                {/foreach}
            {if $i is div by 3}
      </tr>
            {/if}
     </table>
        {/if}